# Why aren't these values passed as props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my code, I pass the value of a hook to a child component and a method to change the value of said hook. However, when I try to log what are the props passed to the child component, the "selected" props always comes back as undefined. I don't understand why since I pass real values to the child component.

Is it because I use hooks ?

Here is the code for my screens and the most importants components :

```
export default function ExerciseSelectorScreen({navigation}) {

    const route = useRoute();
    const {t} = useTranslation();
    var filters = {};

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (route.params?.filters) {
            filters = (route.params?.filters);
        }
      }, [route.params?.post]);


    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={generalStyles.contentContainer}>
            <View style={[generalStyles.contentContainer]}>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <Text style={generalStyles.title}>{ t('exercise.exercises') }</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Exercises Filter', {filters: filters})}} style={{padding: 10, backgroundColor: '#ffb623'}}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{t('general.filters').toUpperCase()}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>        
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

```
export default function ExercisesFilterScreen() {

    const route = useRoute();
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [selectedEquipments, setSelectedEquipments] = useState({});
    const [order, setOrder] = useState('');
    const [machine, setMachine] = useState('yes');
    const [equipments, setEquipments] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        var filters = route.params?.filters;
        console.log('filters')
        console.log(filters)
        if(filters != undefined || Object.values(filters).length != 0) {
            setOrder(filters.order);
            setMachine(filters.machine);
            setSelectedEquipments(filters.selectedEquipments);
        } 
    }, [route.params?.filters])

        return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
            <ScrollView style={[generalStyles.contentContainer, {flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ffb623'}]}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 30, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#ffffff', textAlign: 'center'}}>{t('general.filters').toUpperCase()}</Text>
                <View style={{marginTop: 10}}>
                <CheckboxGroup
                    title={t('exercise.availableEquipment')}
                    selected={selectedEquipments}
                    select={setSelectedEquipments}
                    multi={true}
                    options={
                        equipments
                    }
                />
                <CheckboxGroup
                    title={t('exercise.order')}
                    selected={order}
                    select={setOrder}
                    multi={false}
                    options={
                        {
                            "asc": t('exercise.easyToHard'),
                            "desc": t('exercise.hardToEasy'),
                        }
                    }
                    undefined={'allow'}
                />
                <CheckboxGroup
                    title={t('exercise.machines')}
                    selected={machine}
                    select={setMachine}
                    multi={false}
                    options={
                        {
                            "yes": t('exercise.machine.yes'),
                            "no": t('exercise.machine.no'),
                            "only": t('exercise.machine.only')
                        }
                    }
                />

                <Button onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate('Exercise Selector', {filters: {order: order, machine: machine, selectedEquipments: selectedEquipments }})
                }} title="Applic">Appliquer</Button>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

```
export default function CheckboxGroup(props) {

    const options = props.options;

    console.log(props);
    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.optionTitle}>{props.title.toUpperCase()}</Text>
            {Object.keys(options).map((k) => 
                <CheckboxRow 
                key={k}
                selected={props.selected} 
                select={props.select} 
                multi={props.multi} 
                undefined={props.undefined} 
                id={k}>{options[k]}</CheckboxRow>
            )}
        </View>
    )
}
```

```
export default function CheckboxRow(props) {

    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (props.multi == false) {
            if (props.selected != props.id) {
                setChecked(false);
            }
            if( props.selected == props.id) {
                setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    }, [props.multi, props.selected])

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.row}
            onPress={
                () => {
                    var id = props.id;
                    var selected = props.selected;
                    var s = selected;
                    if(props.multi == true) {
                        if(s[id] == undefined) {
                            s[id] = id;
                        } else {
                            delete s[id];
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(s == id && undefinedAllow == true) {
                            s = undefined;
                        } else {
                            s = id;
                        }
                    }
                    props.select(s)
                    if(s == id && undefinedAllow == false) {
                        setChecked(checked);
                    } else {
                        setChecked(!checked);
                    }
                }
            }>
            <Checkbox checked={checked} />
            <Text style={styles.rowText}>{props.children}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

The error I get from CheckboxRow is that "undefined isn't an object (evaluating s[id])".

Comment: Please only post the relevant code, there's like 250 lines here 90% of which is irrelevant to your question. We don't want to have to hunt through it to find the relevant parts

Comment: I will fix that ASAP, didn't really think about that. So sorry !

Comment: You are initializing `SelectedEquipment` as undefined:
`const [selectedEquipments, setSelectedEquipments] = useState({});`
try to provede some valid initial value there

Comment: @VadimAidlin The problem is that I use that as an array where selected values will get added. Since there isn't any initial value for this input, it wouldn't work. I also have the same problem for the other CheckboxGroups. For example, when the default value is "yes", the value passed to the children component is still "undefined"...